# Best place/way to define context Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, entity-framework

I think there is two main ways (or more) to define Entity framework **Context**:

1. Define one Context in the whole App and then use it during all it's
   life cycle, so here the Context will be disposed after closing the
   app, I defined this variable in MainWindow then I used it in all my app windows and User Conteols

   public static SC_Context Context = new SC_Context();
2. Define the context every time we want to deal with the database and dispose that context after that. In this way, I make partial classes and write method inside:

   using (SC_Context Context = new SC_Context())
   {
       //Bla Bla Bla
   }

Actually, I used both ways in many apps, Websites and Windows apps and I saw many samples and developers using them.

***Simply my question is:***
Which is better -using one context for whole app or use one context for each procedure with DB- for App performance and RAM consumption and **Why**?

Comment: Marked as duplicate, but apart from that this question is too opinion-based for Stack Overflow. That said, the best I've ever read about this is [this](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx) (or this [blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/02/07/entity-framework-context-lifetime-best-practices/)), you should use the second way, with **using** statement. When you use **using**, the compiler automatically creates a `try/finally` block and calls dispose in the `finally` block.

Here are some general guidelines when deciding on the lifetime of the context:

1. When working with Web applications, use a context instance per
   request.
2. When working with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) or Windows
   Forms, use a context instance per form. This lets you use
   change-tracking functionality that context provides.

In conclusion, the rule is: context per request and context per form lifetimes.

Comment: Thnx , these links are very useful :)

Comment: Thanks. Please upvote or mark as answer if you find it useful for you :)